# Eclipse tab key inserts tags

Tags: eclipse

I use Eclipse Luna for PHP. However, after a variable or any word, the tab key does not insert a tab, but it converts the word into a tag. For example, a tab after `$matches` will display `<1matches></1matches>`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was held in **Window -> Preferences -> Emmet -> Expand abbreviations by Tab key** (this option should not be ticked)